# Countif is not counting the summary of my formula (the summury is text)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

This is my formula in the column which I want to count =IF(P3="","",IF(P3>=70%," True "," False "))

and when I use the formula "=countif(p3:p94,"True")"  the result is 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutmC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrKyP.png)

Comment: It seems there is space before and after True in your formula `" True "`. Try removing space then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in first formula " True " with spaces, but in second - without spaces "True"

Use TRUE and FALSE without "" in all cases

```
=IF(P3="","",IF(P3>=70%,True,False))
=COUNTIF(p3:p94,TRUE)
```

or use " True " and " False " in all formulas

or use wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(D4:D27,"*True*")
```

Comment: No, they are string as OP used double quote before and after `True` in `IF()` formula. Problem is space. Look closely.

Comment: Space wasn't the problem. the issue is with text. I removed the space from the formula and the result was still the same but the Wildcards did the job.
thanks for the answer. My problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Алексей-Р's answer, I also recommend not using quotation marks for TRUE and FALSE keywords. Instead, use them directly, and there will be no need of wildcards.
So my suggestion would be

```
=IF(P3="","",IF(P3>=70%,TRUE,FALSE))
```

and for your COUNTIF cells :

```
=COUNTIF(P3:P94, TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you Ali baba, I will keep it in mind.